# How to run QEMU simulation with randomized memory content?

Tags: embedded, qemu

Is there a way to run a binary on QEMU (system mode) starting with randomized memory contents?

My use case is a binary that contains some sort of first-stage bootloader and a user application. I want to test the bootloader and check if all memory sections have been initialized correctly (e.g., that the .bss was zeroed, or that .data was copied), things like that. However, it seems that the QEMU model starts with an all-zero memory, which is not always the case in real silicon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdb's `compare-sections` to see if the data matches what you expect:

```
(gdb) help compare-sections
Compare section data on target to the exec file.
Argument is a single section name (default: all loaded sections).
To compare only read-only loaded sections, specify the -r option.
```

I do not know how to initialize memory with random (or non-zero) patterns on startup...